# QGIS/Mergin Invalid layers

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

I have used Mergin Input on my iphone 12 for a year working with QGIS and it worked okay but now none of my projects will load the layers.

The backdrops appear on the phone but no data. I have logged in and out, deleted some projects, got storage down to 30mb, changed data sources, created a new id but all without luck. It used to work so why not now?

I get a message saying "There were issues loading the project" and an option for Details. This just tells me the layers are unavailable and invalid.

I have loaded Input into both IoS and Android. Initial data constructed in QGIS 3.20.0 Odense on a Mac running Monterey. I got some assistance from elsewhere that identified the issue being too many layers with incorrect datasources but without any clues how to fix. To cap it all the one project that got fixed broke again when editing symbology.

Comment: I suggest posting on the Input github issues page if you haven't already - and have a look to see if anyone else has had the same problem https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues

Comment: I have tried but no responses. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The most probably issue is that your QGIS layers are located outside of the Mergin Maps folder (e.g. you reference geopackage file that is in different folder on your PC than the QGIS project file). To diagnose the issue, please install the latest Mergin Maps Plugin for QGIS and check the project validation. In case you fix all the warnings in the validation and the problem persists, please report issue on the Github issues page

Comment: Hi Peter-  see Github entry